# Accessing certain elements of an array in arm assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, neon

I have a problem which is bugging me for multiple days now...
I call a function from c which is implemented in arm assembler on a raspberry pi using the neon module. The signature looks like the following: 
`void doStuff(const uint32_t key[4])`

I can load all the values into d-registers using `VLD4.32 {d6-d9}, [r0]`.
The problem is that I have to use a value at a certain index of the array which is calculated at runtime. So I have to access the array at an index which I only know at runtime.
In c, the code I want to achieve would look like this:

```
// calculations
int i = ... // 'i' is the index of value in the array
int result = key[i];
```

In assembler I tried this:

```
VMOV        r8, s22         ;@ copy the calculated index into an arm register
MOV         r8, r8, LSL #0x2;@ multiply with 4
ADD         r8, r5, r8      ;@ add offset to base adress
VLDR.32     d14, [r8]         ;@ load from adress into d-register
```

I also tried multiplying with 2 and 32 instead of 4. But I always get the value 3.

I got it working with this stupid and very slow solution:

```
;@ <--- very slow and ugly --->
VLD4.32     {d6-d9}, [r1]   ;@ load 4x32bit from adress *r1

VMOV        r6, s22         ;@ r6 now contains the offset which is either 0,1,2 or 3
CMP         r6, #0x0        ;@ 3 - 0 == 0 -> Z set
BEQ         equal0

CMP         r6, #0x1
BEQ         equal1

CMP         r6, #0x2
BEQ         equal2

VMOV        d12, d9         ;@ has to be 3 
B           continue

equal0:
VMOV        d12, d6
B           continue

equal1:
VMOV        d12, d7
B           continue

equal2:
VMOV        d12, d8
B           continue

continue:
;@ <---                           --->
```

I basically have an if for every possible number and then select the corresponding register.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Okay it works with `VLD1.32 d14, [r8]`. Do not quite unterstand why it won't work with VLDR.32, though.

Comment: Since you can't index registers / vector elements (except with variable shuffles, and IDK if ARM has any instructions like that), it might be better to just delay the load until you know the right index.  Or do something to prefetch all 4 values, but still use an indexed load to select the element you want.  I don't know much about the microarchitecture of the CPU in an rPi, but assuming it has L1 cache, L1 load-use latency is usually 3 to 5 cycles on a lot of microarchitectures.  (e.g. 4 cycles on Intel Haswell, and it runs at much higher frequency).

Comment: I do the load after the calculation of the index. So I know the index when I try loading the value.

Comment: You meant `vld1.32 d14,[r8]` right? You are missing the `[]` for memory reference.

Comment: Thanks @Jester! Now it works. But it still don't unerstand why it wont work with VLDR.32..

Comment: I don't see how `VLDR` is applicable here. `VLDR.32` doesn't seem to be valid but that would also need the `[]` anyway.

Comment: @michidk: Ok, even better.  So just load `d12` from `r1+r6`, whatever the ARM syntax is for that.  No comparisons, no branches, and no `VMOV` instructions.  Use memory addressing instead of branching to select the element of the vector you want, since it's efficient to index memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's exactly what my first try did. I just have to multiply it with 4.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Are you sure you had the right register for the base address?  You're using `r1` in the other block of code.  Check with a debugger, because that's how you should be doing it.  Also, you know you could have written it as `add  r8, r5, r8 LSL #2`, right?  You rarely need an instruction that's *just* a shift (i.e. a mov with a shifted input).  Actually, according to this ARM addressing-modes doc (ftp://www.cs.uregina.ca/pub/class/301/ARM-addressing/lecture.html), you could have just used `VLDR.32 d14, [r5, r8, LSL #2]`

Comment: But calculating the address with separate instructions makes it easy to check with a debugger what address you're loading from.

Comment: `VLD`/`VLDR` do not support such addressing modes and `VLDR.32` doesn't even exist.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking VLDR.S32 d14, [r8] (S)igned or (U)nsigned. May also depend on processor and assembler. You can also choose you array element.